# how can I get sku on product page?

Tags: layout

i am adding a phtml with after_body_start reference

how do I display the SKU of a product if the phtml is being added to a product page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may be a more efficient way depending on how you added this phtml, but if it only shows on a product page, try getting the product like this:

```
$current_product = Mage::registry('current_product');
if($current_product) {
    $sku = $current_product->getSku();
    // output sku
    echo $sku;
}
```

Comment: i am a new user so i could not accept for ten minutes did it now thanks

Comment: Good Edit Abdul

Comment: actually the get Data('sku') format was better for me as they can choose any product attribute as the output for this space        

`<?php $att = Mage::getStoreConfig('options/messages/attribute'); ?>
<?php echo Mage::registry('current_product')->getData($att); ?>"]);`

Comment: Yeah, I agree on getData, but he added the if($current_product) check that I didn't have.  That check was needed

Answer (score 3):

You can try this is code below:

```
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$sku = $_product->getSku();
```

Comment: Whether or not this works depends on what block he is using when he adds it to the page.

Comment: tried that does not work

Comment: I edit this code, because uppercase $sku = $_product->getSku(); it not work. If you in product detail page, it using block `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View`

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me in magento 2.

```
<?php
    if($_product) {
      $sku = $_product->getSku();
      echo $sku;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get product sku in Magento (Adobe Commerce) 2.x.x in your custom phtml template file you need to add the appropriate block class in your layout file, for example:

in catalog_product_view.xml :

```
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="my-block" template="Vendor_Module::custom.phtml" />
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```

in your custom.phtml :

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

/** @var Escaper $escaper */
/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View */

$_product = $block->getProduct();
$sku = $_product->getSku();
?>
<div>
    Product sku: 
    <span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml($sku) ?></span>
</div>
```

You can use methods from different blocks, by declaring the block class on your block tag in xml layout, then call the methods in your custom phtml file.